# Color settings keep popping up by themselves

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic, color-management

Recently, my Ubuntu 14.04 installation is showing a very irritating behavior: every few minutes, the color settings window just pops up out of the blue.

[image]

It says: "Each device needs an up to date profile to be color managed."

I take it it wants me to calibrate my monitor. But I don't have a device to do that, and I don't care.

That it just pops up maybe has to do with the fact that I'm using the GNOME Flashback (Metacity) session and xmonad as window manager.

How can I stop the color settings from popping up by themselves?